# Can't start etcd service OpenStack Install Ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, openstack, etcd

I'm following the OpenStack install guide here (for Queens release) and I'm up to this page:

https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/environment-etcd-ubuntu.html

Both VMs = VirtualBox on Ubuntu 16.04.4.
Each VM has two NICs. First is host-only set to 10.0.0.11 and 10.0.0.21 (controller and compute node respectively). Second NIC is NAT (for net access).

I **can** ping between controller (10.0.0.11) and compute (10.0.0.21).

I've installed and configured etcd but when I try to run it: `systemctl start etcd` it fails to run.

Looking at `journalctl -xe` I see:

`listen tcp 10.0.0.11:2379: bind: cannot assign requested address`

Strangely if I do an `ifconfig`, I only see an ipv6 address assigned to enp0s3

```
enp0s3 Link encap: Ethernet HWaddr ****
inet6 addr: fe80::***** Scope:Link
UP BORADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
...
```

Comment: Did you figure this one out?